host Address is [::] When i run my dotnet 9 api on docker
I have an API with .NET 9
while I run the API directory by Kestrel or IIS everything is ok and openapi/v1.json is like this :
  "open API": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "title": "Scientometrics.Api.v3 | v1",
    "version": "1.0.0"
  },
  "servers": [
    {
      "url": "https://localhost:7226"
    },
    {
      "url": "http://localhost:5051"
    }
  ],

but when I run it on the docker desktop on windows the server URL in the openapi document is
http://[::]:8080
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "title": "Scientometrics.Api.v3 | v1",
    "version": "1.0.0"
  },
  "servers": [
    {
      "url": "http://[::]:8080"
    }
  ],

scalar ui
and in requesting to API by scalar or swaggerui give Network Error when attempting to fetch resource
but API with address http://localhost:8080 works correctly
I even created a new project but the problem persists
And this is my docker file
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:9.0 AS base
USER $APP_UID
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8081

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:9.0 AS build
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Scientometrics.Api.v3/Scientometrics.Api.v3.csproj", "Scientometrics.Api.v3/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Scientometrics.Api.v3/Scientometrics.Api.v3.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Scientometrics.Api.v3"
RUN dotnet build "Scientometrics.Api.v3.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
ARG BUILD_CONFIGURATION=Release
RUN dotnet publish "Scientometrics.Api.v3.csproj" -c $BUILD_CONFIGURATION -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Scientometrics.Api.v3.dll"]


:: is the ipv6 equivalent of the ipv4 0.0.0.0, with the [ and ] not part of the address. You connect to it using http://:::8080 (e.g. :: as address, and then :8080 for the port suffix). See https://serverfault.com/questions/444554/what-does-mean-as-an-ip-address-bracket-colon-colon-bracket

Try to add "ipv6": false in daemon.json file to disable ipv6, or you can use builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options => {     options.Listen(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0"), 8080);  });.
